# как сделать USSD запрос кликабельным телеграмм бот

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Если в ТГ бот просто напишите, то номер +79991234567 будет показано как ссылка и при нажатии вы попадаете на набор этого номера. Возможно ли это сделать для USSD запроса. Например, *111#
bot.send_message(chat_id, "Example text with a phone +79991234567")

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options
```[*111#](tel:*111#)```

Comment: Не понял как это использовать на самом коде

Comment: Можно через HTML страницу через <a href=tel: *111%23> </a>. Но при нажатии с начало на сам сайт отправляет потом уже на набор номера на телефоне. Хотелось бы промежуток HTML сайта не было при нажатии на кнопку в ТГ бот

Comment: только так и можно, первый совет - ссылка в разметке markdown которую принимает телеграм бот апи :) (вы написали вторым комментарием тоже самое решение в разметке html)